# Combined fields into array

Tags: php, arrays, json, web-crawler

I have a code to crawler data-

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

// Restore error level
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$result=array();

$link = $xpath->query($linkPath);
$title = $xpath->query($titlePath);
$desc = $xpath->query($descPath);

for ($i=0; $i < $link->length; $i++) { 
        if (!is_null($link)) {
                $result['link'][] = $link[$i]->getAttribute('href');
        }

        if (!is_null($title)) {
                $str = $title[0]->nodeValue;
                $result['title'][] = $title[$i]->nodeValue;
        }

        if (!is_null($desc)) {
                $str = $desc[0]->nodeValue;
                $result['desc'][] = $desc[$i]->nodeValue;
        }
        echo "<br> ----------------";
}

print_r($result);
```

Result like:

```
<br> ----------------
<br> ----------------
<br> ----------------
<br> ----------------
<br> ----------------
Array
(
    [link] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; http://1.com
            [1] =&gt; http://2.com
            [2] =&gt; http://3.com
        )

    [title] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            [1] =&gt; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            [2] =&gt; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [desc] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            [1] =&gt; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            [2] =&gt; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

)
```

But I want result like:

```
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Array 
    (
        [link] =&gt; http://1.com
        [title] =&gt; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        [desc] =&gt; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    )
    <br> ----------------
    [1] =&gt; Array 
    (
        [link] =&gt; http://2.com
        [title] =&gt; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        [desc] =&gt; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    )
    <br> ----------------
    [2] =&gt; Array 
    (
        [link] =&gt; http://3.com
        [title] =&gt; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        [desc] =&gt; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    )
    <br> ----------------
)
```

I using `$result['field'][]`, if using `result['field']` only get final rows when loop.

I don't know how to save data like before format.
I need array show like this because each array is a news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like below:-

```
for ($i=0; $i < $link->length; $i++) { 
    if (!is_null($link)) {
        $result[$i]['link'] = $link[$i]->getAttribute('href'); // will produce like $result[0]['link']
    }

    if (!is_null($title)) {
        $str = $title[0]->nodeValue;
        $result[$i]['title'] = $title[$i]->nodeValue;// will produce like $result[0]['title']
    }

    if (!is_null($desc)) {
        $str = $desc[0]->nodeValue;
        $result[$i]['desc'] = $desc[$i]->nodeValue;// will produce like $result[0]['index']
    }
    echo "<br> ----------------";
}
```

Comment: @vanloc  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayofcol=array(1=>"link",2=>"title",3=>"desc");
$title=$desc=$link;
$result = array();
$data=$arrayofcol[1];

$new_program=$$data;

print_r($new_program);
```

you will get expected result.

Comment: nope man. it will work in case of single dimensional array but not incase of multidimensional array.try to check it  with some hard-code value

Comment: like @Anant comment. You should edit your answer. Thanks.

Comment: if possible could you please send me the link of $url ($doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
) so i can check ..

Comment: @AvinashRaut  : `$url = "http://giaitri.vnexpress.net/"`. `$linkPath & $titlePath = "//*[@id='news_home']/li/h3/a[1]"` . `$desc = "'//*[@class="block_image_news width_common"]/div[2]'"`.

Comment: @vanloc : pl see edited answer it will helpful to u.

Comment: @AvinashRaut  i have given you an example. and you added it as an answer. his question is far beyond your answer. i just gave an example for your understanding man.

Comment: pl try with this code, remove 'for' loop  and add above code.